# pykafka:Socket disconnected during offset manager discovery

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, pykafka

This is my code：
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ne0a.png)

​When I run it,it will warn me: Socket disconnected during offset manager discovery
So I use Ctrl+C to stop it
Then
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtODu.png)

I need your help ,what should I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post code into your question rather than as an external link.  Read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's hard to debug this error without more information. What versions of pykafka/kafka are you using? The interesting thing is that the metadata request is succeeding, but the group coordinator request is failing. Make sure that the machine you're running this code from has ssh access to each of the brokers in your kafka cluster.